# PhpStorm editor auto copy text after typed

Tags: php, phpstorm, editor

I got problem when edit code in PhpStorm.

I don't know how to explain my problem, so please take a look these pictures:

1. I want to edit `$a` from `1` to `150`, `$c` from `3` to `30`:

   [image: I want to edit $a from 1 to 150, $c from 3 to 30]
2. I edit param `$a` like this:

   [image: I edit param <code>$a</code> like this]
3. Then I continue edit param `$c`:

   [image: Then I continue edit param <code>$c</code>]
4. But after I typed `0` to change param `$c` from `3` to `30`, the text `50` from param `$a` auto go here:

   [image: But after I typed <code>0</code> to change param <code>$c</code> from <code>3</code> to <code>30</code>, the text <code>50</code> from param <code>$a</code> auto go here]

I can avoid this problem by using `Space` or `Esc` after edit param `$a`, but sometimes, I forgot and this problem occur.

How can I turn off this function in PhpStorm?

Comment: No idea. Better record some video that will illustrate the issue -- maybe it will reveal more details/nuances. Other than that: please disable all 3rd party (not bundled by default) plugins and try again (after IDE restart, of course). Maybe it's some IdeaVim plugin or something....

Comment: Thank you LazyOne! I found this problem is not from phpstorm. It's because of my macbook input source. I changed input source to U.S and everything is OK